# How to Delete a Reference in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

When I am editing references, I cannot delete references that I have listed:

[image]

I have tried right clicking it or selecting it and looking for a delete button.

There is the giant X button on the right hand side of the "Edit References" page:

[image]

However, this just deletes it from the selected references. I want to permanently delete these references from appearing in my list. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution window, expand the References node, right-click on the DLL you want to remove, and select "Delete"